# All code is formatted, the only URL is escaped, but still unable to post (Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.)

Tags: support

I'm trying to post this question on StackOverflow. As you will see, all the code is indented and the only URL is escaped. I tried to "clean" file paths, reducing them to only two components, but it was unuseful. Might file paths containing directories be expected to confuse the parser?

```
I'm on *Tomcat 7.0.30*. I'm developing my own webapp, named *MyWebApp* made up of a single servlet, named *MyServlet* (it isn't its real name, I'm just avoiding the exposure of possibly critical resource names). It can be reached at the URL `https://<hostname>/MyWebApp/MyServlet`. I want to add a very basic authentication mechanism to this webapp. Therefore, I firstly defined the webapp context in **webapps/MyWebApp/META-INF/context.xml** (I am posting the whole file):

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/MyWebApp/MyServlet">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" failureCount="5" lockOutTime="60" >
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="MyWebAppUserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
    </Context>

The context refers to a resource named *MyWebAppUserDatabase*, which is defined in **conf/server.xml**, beside the usual *UserDatabase*:

    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
      <!-- Other stuff /-->

      <!-- Global JNDI resources
           Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
      -->
      <GlobalNamingResources>
        <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
             UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
        -->
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                  description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                  pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
        <Resource name="MyWebAppUserDatabase" auth="Container"
                  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                  description="User database for MyWebApp"
                  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                  pathname="conf/mywebapp-users.xml" />
      </GlobalNamingResources>

In the end, I define my users, in **conf/mywebapp-users.xml**:
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <tomcat-users>
        <user username="username" roles="client" password="password" />
    </tomcat-users>

Unfortunately, when I connect to the former URL, no connection popup is shown. Therefore, I configured **conf/logging.properties**: so that:

    1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = -1
    org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL
    org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true

I read through Tomcat logs and I found that:

    Jan 08, 2014 7:45:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\MyWebApp.war
    Jan 08, 2014 7:45:15 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase startInternal
    FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present

and

    FINE: Security checking request GET /MyWebApp/MyServlet
    Jan 08, 2014 7:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints
    FINE:   No applicable constraints defined
    Jan 08, 2014 7:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
    FINE:  Not subject to any constraint

What should I do, in order for the login popup to appear?
```

Comment: You should probably put a new line before your `conf/mywebapp-users.xml` file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a newline here:

```
In the end, I define my users, in **conf/mywebapp-users.xml**:
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <tomcat-users>
        <user username="username" roles="client" password="password" />
    </tomcat-users>
```

to separate the XML code block from the sentence:

```
In the end, I define my users, in **conf/mywebapp-users.xml**:

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <tomcat-users>
        <user username="username" roles="client" password="password" />
    </tomcat-users>
```

Without the newline, your post would look like:

> In the end, I define my users, in **conf/mywebapp-users.xml**:

instead of:

> In the end, I define my users, in **conf/mywebapp-users.xml**:
>
> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
> <tomcat-users>
>     <user username="username" roles="client" password="password" />
> </tomcat-users>
> ```

As an aside, I'd use backticks instead of bolding for filenames; not **webapps/MyWebApp/META-INF/context.xml**, but `webapps/MyWebApp/META-INF/context.xml`.

Comment: Still not enough reputation to upvote :-(
Already enough gratitude to say "thanks"! :-)